# Regular expression between special symbols

Tags: c#, regex

I have got following `regex` and it fails.

In this regex I need to get all characters between `+` and `#`

```
var regexMN = new Regex("+(.*)#");
var mn = regexMN.Match(tranFileName);
r.MachineNumber = mn.Groups[1].ToString();
```

And here between `#` and `.`

```
var regexTN = new Regex("#(.*).");
var tn = regexTN.Match(tranFileName);
r.TransactionNumber = tn.Groups[1].ToString();
```

Any clue?

Comment: You would need to escape the "+" and the "." as they have regex meanings of their own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` and `.` have special meaning inside regexes. If you want to search for a plus character, or a dot, you must prepend it with a `\`.

```
var regexMN = new Regex(@"\+(.*)#");
```

And

```
var regexTN = new Regex(@"#(.*)\.");
```

Comment: I'd also recommend to change the part within the group to `[^#]*`, or `[^.]*`, respectively. This also has the benefit of performing better.

Comment: @Joey Would you mind to add your explanation as an answer, please.

Comment: To make life even more fun \ has a special meaning to C# as well if you are not using verbatim string literals as this answer does. If you use normal strings you have to double the slash like this: "\\+(.*)#"